# Agrupar valores de una Matriz para Listar Datos de forma Horizontal en PHP

Tags: laravel, lista

Un cordial Saludo a Toda la Comunidad
Quisiera Agrupar los datos de un array que pertenecen al mismo usuario pero en diferentes días del mes y mostrarlos en una tabla de forma Horizontal, cuando trato de listar con un Foreach me lo hace de manera Vertical repitiendo el mismo usuario varias veces este es mi código espero me puedan ayudar muchas Gracias de ante mano

```
public function SellerRequestTotalDays()
{
 $AssociateRequestWithSeller = AssociateRequestWithSeller::all();

 foreach($AssociateRequestWithSeller as $seller){
  $IdSeller = $seller->seller_id;           
  $User = User::find($IdSeller); 
  $Count = AssociateRequestWithSeller::where('seller_id',$IdSeller)
                                    ->orderBy('signature_date', 'ASC')->get();
  $CountData = count($Count);
            
   }
 foreach($Count as $Countas){
  $DateFormat = $Countas->signature_date->format('d-m-Y');
  $CountF = AssociateRequestWithSeller::where('seller_id',$IdSeller)
                                      ->where('signature_date',$Countas->signature_date)
                                      ->orderBy('signature_date', 'ASC')->get();
  $CountDate = count($CountF);
     $datas = [
      'id'     => $Countas->id,
      'data'   => $CountDate,
      'total'  => $CountData,
      'date'   => $DateFormat,
      'name'   => $User->name
      ];
      $data[] = $datas;
  }
        return view('content.seller_request_total_days_report', compact('data'));
}
```

**Modelo AssociateRequestWithSeller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AssociateRequestWithSeller extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

            /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'associate_request_with_sellers';
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'signature_date'
    ];
    protected $fillable = [
        'provider_id',
        'seller_id',
        'application_number',
        'signature_date',
        'application_registration_date',
        'application_approval_date',
        'client_name',
        'client_surnames',
        'procesado'
 
    ];
}
```

**Modelo User**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use App\Models\Network;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasRoles;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    //protected $guard_name = 'sactum';
    //protected $guard_name = 'web';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'dni',
        'ruc',
        'email',
        'email_verified_at',
        'code',
        'contract',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];


    public function networks(){
        return $this->HasMany(Network::class, 'sender_user_id', 'sender_fullname','receiver_user_id', 'receiver_fullname');
    } 
}
```

y el HTML es este

```
@include('skeleton.header')
<body>
    <div id="app"><!-- vue id -->
    <!-- Begin page -->
            <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- Topbar Start -->
                @include('topbar.topbar')
            <!-- end Topbar -->
            <!-- ========== Left Sidebar Start ========== -->
                @include('sidebar.sidebar')
            <!-- Left Sidebar End -->
            <div class="content-page">
            <div class="content">
        <!-- Start Content-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- start page title -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="page-title-box">
                        <div class="page-title-right">
                            <ol class="breadcrumb m-0">
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Lifeconsys</a></li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Apps</a></li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Reporte Total de solicitudes del Vendedor</li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                        <h4 class="page-title">Reporte Total de solicitudes del Vendedor</h4>
                    </div><!-- end page title -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- end row -->
            <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
@if ($data !== 0 )    
<!-- Users Section-->
<div class="table-responsive">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <!--  <div class="card">-->
                <!-- <div class="card-body">-->
                    <h4 class="header-title">Datos de Red</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted font-13 mb-4">
                    </p>
                    <table id="table table-bordered" class="table table-bordered mb-0">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre del Usuario</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">01/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">02/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">03/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">04/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">05/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">06/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">07/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">08/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">09/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">10/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">11/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">12/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">13/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">14/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">15/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">16/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">17/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">18/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">19/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">20/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">21/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">22/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">23/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">24/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">25/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">26/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">27/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">28/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">29/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">30/01/2021</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">31/01/2021</th>
                            <th>total de solicitudes</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>                                               
                    @foreach ($data as $datas) 
                        <tr>
                        
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['name'] ?? "Nombre" }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '01-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '02-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '03-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '04-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '05-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '06-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '07-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '08-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '09-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '10-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '11-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '12-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '13-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '14-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '15-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '16-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '17-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '18-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '19-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '20-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '21-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '22-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '23-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '24-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '25-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '26-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '27-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '28-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '29-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '30-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            @if ($datas['date'] === '31-01-2021' )
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['data'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>0</small></p>
                            </td>
                            @endif
                            <td>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"><small>{{ $datas['date'] }}</small></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>     
                    @endforeach   
                        </tbody>
                    </table>  
                <!--  </div> <!-- end card body-->
            <!-- </div> <!-- end card -->
        </div><!-- end col-->
    </div> <!-- end row-->
</div> <!-- end row-->


            @else
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
   
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myCenterModalLabel">No hay Datos Registrados</h4>
                <br>
                 <div class="row">
                            <div class="col"></div>
                            <div class="col-5"><div id="CalendarioWeb"></div></div>
                            <div class="col"></div>
                        </div>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Registro de Ventas Diarias</h3>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div id="calendar1"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            
            @endif 

            </div> <!-- container -->
        </div> <!-- content -->
    </div><!-- end wrapper -->
</div><!-- end vue id -->            
@include('skeleton.footer_full')
```

**Este es el var_dump de los Datos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**A si me queda la tabla**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y así debería Quedar**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero Agrupar todos los Datos de la Consulta en una sola Fila en la Tabla de manera de que muestren todas las ventas que se hicieron por ese usuario en esa fecha y a si poblar toda la tabla de manera Horizontal

Comment: Como tienes tus modelos?

Comment: Este es el modelo de de la Consulta por Fechas : AssociateRequestWithSeller
`     protected $table = 'associate_request_with_sellers';
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'signature_date'
    ];
    protected $fillable = [
        'provider_id',
        'seller_id',
        'application_number',
        'signature_date',
        'application_registration_date',
        'application_approval_date',
        'client_name',
        'client_surnames',
        'procesado'
`
y el Modelo User esta Tal cual lo crea Laravel

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega este codigo con las tags correspondientes, ya que aqui es dificl leerlo

Comment: actualizado, si necesitas que coloque algo mas estaré atento

Comment: ¿lograste resolver? estoy teniendo el mismo problema